# complex entity framework query

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I am struggling with a complex EF query

The query is passed an Integer which defines the number of days to look back at a stocks closing price to determine if each day from the most recent was lower then the prior (ie see if the price was lower each day in the lookback period) I am struggling with how to incorporate the price test. I can retrieve the requisite number of days but am unsure if i can do the whole process in one query or if it should be broken up into another query to get the result. Any help appreciated. (AddBusinessDays is my own function to only use businessdays)

```
 Public Shared Function GetDailyEquityDownMoves(ByVal numdaysback As Int32) As List(Of String)
    Dim qualifiedDownStocks As New List(Of String)
    Using ctx As New QE2DatabaseEntities()
        Dim symblist As List(Of Int64) = (From sym In ctx.symbols Select sym.idsymbols).ToList()
        For Each symId As Int64 In symblist
            Dim query = (From q In ctx.pricedatas
                             Where q.symid = symId
                             Join d In ctx.symbols On d.idsymbols Equals symId
                             Where q.pricedate < DateTime.Now AndAlso q.pricedate > AddBusinessDays(DateTime.Now.AddDays(numdaysback * -1))
                             Order By q.pricedate Ascending
                             Select q.closeprice).ToList()
            'Now test to see if each closeprice is less than the prior starting with most recent date
            'if it qualifies add it to the list
            'qualifiedDownStocks.Add(result)

        Next



    End Using
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You REALLY should have Option Strict On.  Since it's not, I had to guess at datatypes since you didn't strongly type your query.  Also, you didn't say exactly what you want to add to your list, so I guessed `symId`.  Change that part if my guess was wrong.  Anyways, see if something like this will work:

```
Public Shared Function GetDailyEquityDownMoves(ByVal numdaysback As Int32) As List(Of String)
    Dim qualifiedDownStocks As New List(Of String)
    Using ctx As New QE2DatabaseEntities()
        Dim symblist As List(Of Int64) = ctx.symbols.ToList        

        For Each symId As Int64 In symblist
            Dim previousPrice As Integer = 0
            Dim query As IEnumerable (Of pricedata) = (From q In ctx.pricedatas
                                                       Where q.symid = symId
                                                       Join d In ctx.symbols On d.idsymbols Equals symId
                                                       Where q.pricedate < DateTime.Now  AndAlso q.pricedate > AddBusinessDays(DateTime.Now.AddDays(numdaysback * -1))
                                                       Order By q.pricedate Ascending
                                                       Select q)

            'Now test to see if each closeprice is less than the prior starting with most recent date
            For Each closing As pricedata In query
                Dim closingPrice As Decimal = closing.closeprice
                'if it qualifies add it to the list
                If closingPrice < previousPrice Then
                    qualifiedDownStocks.Add(closing.symId & vbTab & closing.pricedate)
                End If
                previousPrice = closingPrice
            Next

        Next       

    End Using
End Function
```

You can probably do the whole thing with LINQ, but I left the For Each loops because it makes the whole thing a little easier to follow than one giant LINQ statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, enroute home, will test when there